# How to make this python code more efficient using cuda?

Tags: python-3.x

transform() inter-changes the position of quadrant 1,3 and 2,4. How can i make this code more efficient using cuda support for python? I have a nvidia quardo 4gb gpu and cuda support for python installed.

For better visualization see the diagarm :
[diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DocxE.jpg)

```py
import numpy as np

def transform(a):
    quar = a.shape[0]//2

    for i in range(quar):
        for j in range(quar):
            a[i][j],a[i+quar][j+quar] =  a[i+quar][j+quar],a[i][j]

    for i in range(quar):
        for j in range(quar):
            a[i+quar][j], a[i][j+quar] = a[i][j+quar],a[i+quar][j]

    return a

matrix = np.arange(1,17).reshape(4,4)
print(matrix)

transform(matrix)
```

Output:

```
[[ 1  2  3  4]
 [ 5  6  7  8]
 [ 9 10 11 12]
 [13 14 15 16]]

array([[11, 12,  9, 10],
       [15, 16, 13, 14],
       [ 3,  4,  1,  2],
       [ 7,  8,  5,  6]])
```

Comment: You may be able to do that with the Numba library

Comment: Is there a reason why you are moving individual elements instead of entire quadrants? Slicing the matrix into its quadrants and merging them again should be significantly faster.

Comment: Are you looking for a cuda solution in specific or just a more efficient version? You can directly exchange pairs of quadrants. For example, ``a[quad:,quad:], a[:quad,:quad] = a[:quad,:quad], a[quad:,quad:].copy()`` swaps quadrants 1 and 3.